# Mean of sum in a DataFrame with Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, mean

I create a DataFrame df1  which contains for each day of the week the number of activation time for each machine.

```
machine1    38696 non-null float64
machine3    38697 non-null float64
machine5    38695 non-null float64
machine6    38695 non-null float64
machine7    38693 non-null float64
machine8    38696 non-null float64
date                      38840 non-null datetime64[ns]
day_of_week               38840 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(6), object(1)
memory usage: 2.7+ MB



Machine1 Machine3 Machine5 Machine6 Machine7 Machine8 date day_of_week
90.0 90.0 90.0 90.0 90.0 90.0 2015-07-31 Fri 
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2015-07-31 Mon
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2015-07-31 Tues
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2015-07-31 Fri 
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2015-07-31 Tues
```

I try to create another DataFrame which extracts for each machine the mean of activation per day. For example:

```
            Machine1 Machine3 Machine5 Machine6 Machine7 Machine8
Mon           0          ..     ..       ..       ..        ..
Tue           0
wed           0
thu            0
fri           45
```

Can you help me to achieve this in the smartest way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can use:

```
print (df.groupby('day_of_week').mean())
             Machine1  Machine3  Machine5  Machine6  Machine7  Machine8
day_of_week                                                            
Fri              45.0      45.0      45.0      45.0      45.0      45.0
Mon               0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
Tues              0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
```

If need output with reseting index:

```
print (df.groupby('day_of_week', as_index=False).mean())
  day_of_week  Machine1  Machine3  Machine5  Machine6  Machine7  Machine8
0         Fri      45.0      45.0      45.0      45.0      45.0      45.0
1         Mon       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
2        Tues       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
```

Comment: I am not sure if understand your question. Why in your sample is `45` in `Monday`? Is it typo?